# item from ConcreteClass in C# does not properly work with both GET and POST call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, post, get, entity

I'm very new to web programming, its my first project using anything related to WEB stuff, so please be gentle.

I'm using an InMemoryDatabase from Entity Framework from which I want to send with a GET method, some data about a Project and also to receive some with a POST method. The problem is I can't get them both to work.

The project class looks like this:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public IList<WorkEntry> WorkEntries { get; } = new List<WorkEntry>();

    public Project(string name, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        Id = Stubs.getUniqueID();
        Name = name;
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
    }
}
```

And I'm doing the get call like this:

```
    // GET api/projects
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() //async
    {
        return Ok(_context.Projects);
    }
```

My problem is that when I send this information over on in front-end I get an empty array for WorkEntries even if I clearly set it like this:

```
    var testProject1 = new Project("...", new System.DateTime(...), new System.DateTime(...));
    Stubs.PopulateWorkEntries(testProject1);

    context.Projects.Add(testProject1);

    context.SaveChanges();
```

PopulateWorkEntries just returns an array with values for workEntries I double check, and indeed that information is there, but does not get on from the get call.

I used multiple configurations for my class but some work with get but not with POST for example this one:

```
    public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public List<WorkEntry> WorkEntries { get; set; }

    public Project( string name, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        Id = Stubs.getUniqueID();
        Name = name;
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
        WorkEntries = PopulateWorkEntries(StartDate, EndDate);
    }
```

This one get WorkEntires to front end, but once I add empty constructor for POST method to work, it will stop send WorkEntries with get aswell. In both examples WorkEnties is populated with valid data.

So the problem is I can't get them both GET and POST to work. I only manage to make 1 work. I tried debugging but I had no luck finding anything

Comment: i think you need an empty constructor to work with EF, like : public Project(){}

Comment: you also need to call the child collections with the Include function

Answer (score 1):

you need a empty constructor on your class "Project", try change your class to this:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public IList<WorkEntry> WorkEntries { get; } = new List<WorkEntry>();

    public Project(string name, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        Id = Stubs.getUniqueID();
        Name = name;
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
    }
 
    public Project(){}
}
```

this is because the EntityFramework need a constructor without parameters to generate objects when call from database

so, to call with child collections you can call with the Include function:

```
// GET api/projects
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() //async
{
   return Ok(_context.Projects.Include(x => x.WorkEntries));
}
```

please read this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed this was all that was missing

Comment: Any idea why after using this logic like this : var updatedProject = _context.Projects.Include(x => x.WorkEntries).FirstOrDefault(x =>x.Id ==id); i get an error The instance of entity type 'WorkEntry' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.?

Comment: this happens when i try to SaveChanges. Bu before saving im also detaching like this:      _context.Entry<Project>(updatedProject).State = EntityState.Detached;
     _context.SaveChanges();

Comment: maybe, you have an instance of that object in memory,do you dont call any other same object before?, try call only one time the object